# Regex for matching an optional expression after arbitrary amount of ignored lines

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I need to parse a configuration file with some optional fields and I'm not interested in all of them. I'm using Python `re.findall` method for this.

Be this piece of configuration:

```
edit 750
    set srcintf "port1"
    set dstintf "port9"
        set srcaddr "addr1" "addr5"             
        set dstaddr "addr6"             
    set action accept
    set schedule "always"
        set service "ICMP_ANY"             
    set logtraffic enable
    set comments "This is the second one"
    set nat enable
    set ippool enable
        set poolname "name1"             
next
```

And this is the regular expression I got so far:

```
r'edit ([\d]+)\s+set srcintf "(.+?)"\s+set dstintf "(.+?)"\s+set srcaddr (.+?)\s+set dstaddr (.+?)\s+set action ([\w]+)\s+(?:set status ([\w]+)\s+)?set schedule "(.+?)"\s+set service (.+?)\s+(?:set .*?\s+)*?(?:set poolname "(.+?)"\s+)?(?:set .*\s+)*?next'
```

Simply put, I want to ignore anything after `set service` but yield the optional field `poolname`.

The problem with my regex is that `(?:set .*?\s+)*?` is consuming the `set poolname` field despite the non-greedy marker.

If `poolname` was mandatory, the regex would work perfectly, but this is not the case. Any thoughts?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are using regex for this ... it seems like `str.split` may be a better technique given what you want to accomplish (the -1 wasnt me by the way)

Comment: Are there many `edit...next` block that you need to parse at once or just one?

Comment: There are many. Like a thousand of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its fairly easy, just introduce a negative lookahead `(?! .. )`
Recommend using [RegexFormat](http://www.regexformat.com) to process large regex's like this

```
 #  edit[ ]([\d]+)\s+set[ ]srcintf[ ]"(.+?)"\s+set[ ]dstintf[ ]"(.+?)"\s+set[ ]srcaddr[ ](.+?)\s+set[ ]dstaddr[ ](.+?)\s+set[ ]action[ ]([\w]+)\s+(?:set[ ]status[ ]([\w]+)\s+)?set[ ]schedule[ ]"(.+?)"\s+set[ ]service[ ](.+?)\s+(?:set[ ](?!poolname[ ]".+?").*?\s+)*(?:set[ ]poolname[ ]"(.+?)"\s+)?(?:set[ ].*\s+)*next

 edit [ ] 
 ( [\d]+ )                          # (1)
 \s+ set [ ] srcintf [ ] "
 ( .+? )                            # (2)
 " \s+ set [ ] dstintf [ ] "
 ( .+? )                            # (3)
 " \s+ set [ ] srcaddr [ ] 
 ( .+? )                            # (4)
 \s+ set [ ] dstaddr [ ] 
 ( .+? )                            # (5)
 \s+ set [ ] action [ ] 
 ( [\w]+ )                          # (6)
 \s+ 
 (?:
      set [ ] status [ ] 
      ( [\w]+ )                     # (7)
      \s+ 
 )?
 set [ ] schedule [ ] "
 ( .+? )                            # (8)
 " \s+ set [ ] service [ ] 
 ( .+? )                            # (9)
 \s+ 
 (?:
      set [ ] 
      (?! poolname [ ] " .+? " )
      .*? 
      \s+ 
 )*
 (?:
      set [ ] poolname [ ] "
      ( .+? )                       # (10)
      " \s+ 
 )?
 (?: set [ ] .* \s+ )*
 next
```

Perl test case

```
$/ = undef;

$str = <DATA>;

while ( $str =~ /edit[ ]([\d]+)\s+set[ ]srcintf[ ]"(.+?)"\s+set[ ]dstintf[ ]"(.+?)"\s+set[ ]srcaddr[ ](.+?)\s+set[ ]dstaddr[ ](.+?)\s+set[ ]action[ ]([\w]+)\s+(?:set[ ]status[ ]([\w]+)\s+)?set[ ]schedule[ ]"(.+?)"\s+set[ ]service[ ](.+?)\s+(?:set[ ](?!poolname[ ]".+?").*?\s+)*(?:set[ ]poolname[ ]"(.+?)"\s+)?(?:set[ ].*\s+)*next/g )
{
    print "----------------------\n";
    print "1 = $1\n";
    print "2 = $2\n";
    print "3 = $3\n";
    print "4 = $4\n";
    print "5 = $5\n";
    print "6 = $6\n";
    print "7 = $7\n";
    print "8 = $8\n";
    print "9 = $9\n";
    print "Poolname = $10\n";
}


__DATA__

edit 750
    set srcintf "port1"
    set dstintf "port9"
        set srcaddr "addr1" "addr5"             
        set dstaddr "addr6"             
    set action accept
    set schedule "always"
        set service "ICMP_ANY"             
    set logtraffic enable
    set comments "This is the second one"
    set nat enable
    set ippool enable
        set poolname "name1"             
next
```

Output >>

```
----------------------
1 = 750
2 = port1
3 = port9
4 = "addr1" "addr5"
5 = "addr6"
6 = accept
7 =
8 = always
9 = "ICMP_ANY"
Poolname = name1
```

Comment: I've been struggling with this negative lookahead for a while before I decided to post this question. I don't know what I was missing, but now it works. Thank you.